# How to define a generic map in proto file for entries in map<string, Object> in java?

Tags: protobuf-java

I'm trying to write a proto file having generic map so that when I fetch the data from database in json format, it can be converted to proto format? Is there anyway to do this ?

[Here is the image of the entries present in the database for which, proto file needs to written.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2etka.png)

For example: I need to write a generic map in proto file in such a way that all the entries in the "PROPERTY_CATEGORY" should be converted to proto.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an Any or a struct to accomplish this

1. `map<string, google.protobuf.Any>`
2. Struct https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto#L51